# Qt Application Slowing Down

Tags: c++, qt, embedded-linux

I have an application developed in Qt on the Beaglebone. It has a number of screen and the application moves back and forth (when the user clicks a button) using the code below.

```
Startup *j = new Startup();
j->showMaximized();
j->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
this->close();
```

However, after a clicking through a few screens the application slows down a lot.  Htop doesn't show any appreciable increase in memory or CPU consumption but the UI slows down considerably.

I tried to install valgrind on the Beaglebone so I could try to get some data but there seems to be problems with the glibc on the Beaglebone.

I've been told that the slowdown is due to memory leaks and I should have designed it differently but time is short.

Whats the fastest way to get the application running as responsively as possible without a redesign?

Jas

Comment: That's hard to tell without knowing your application. The few lines of code above don't help without context. I'd first try to reproduce the issue on the desktop, then you can use valgrind/callgrind or another profiler, e.g. gprof easily. If there are massive memory leaks, there's no way around fixing them.

Comment: This question needs more information.  There are a couple of gotcha's that could be getting you.  Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose causes a deletelater() to be scheduled in the eventloop.  So if your app is switching eventloops( ie, any of your screens are modal ) or if they exist in threads without an event loop, the delete will never happen.